# UITableview First cell on weird position underneath UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

The first cell of my tableView inside my UITableViewController starts just a bit in/underneath my UINavigationController. How can I fix this? I already tried: 
`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(63, 0, 0, 0)` inside my `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` both did help a bit but only after scrolling..

---

[image: example]

Comment: Did you try adding the following for your view controller tableController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom; or 
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO

Comment: Could you show the constraints applied to the UIViewTable?

Comment: FIXED: It had to do with translucency. It ignored a lot of thing due to the face that this was enabled.